# OperationalError at /admin/learning_logs/example/

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am a beginner at the `django` and module and web applications.

Here is the traceback and the data:

```
OperationalError at /admin/learning_logs/example/
no such column: learning_logs_example.entry_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/learning_logs/example/
Django Version: 1.11.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: learning_logs_example.entry_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\LEARNI~1\ll_env\lib\site-
packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py in execute, line 328
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Bryan\Desktop\LEARNI~1\ll_env\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.2
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Bryan\\Desktop\\learning log',
 'C:\\Users\\Bryan\\Desktop\\LEARNI~1\\ll_env\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Bryan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Bryan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Bryan\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32',
 'C:\\Users\\Bryan\\Desktop\\LEARNI~1\\ll_env',
 'C:\\Users\\Bryan\\Desktop\\LEARNI~1\\ll_env\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 18 Nov 2017 18:36:14 +0000
```

For some reason, when I click that link that says "Examples" below,

[image]

it says this

[image]

I tried migrating but it says

```
(venv) C:\...\learning log>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

(venv) C:\...\learning log>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

**How did I get it to do that?**

Well first I added the `example` entry/form with a `TextField` and then I added a "example". I added a `ForeignKey` object with the parameter as `Entry`.

I went back to edit my "example" but then the exception showed up.

**EDIT:** 
Well janos wanted the output when I run `python manage.py showmigrations learning_logs` so here it is:

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 001_initial
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
learning_logs
 [X] 0001_initial
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

Well I hope that helped.

I recreated the exception page right [here](https://thimbleprojects.org/HTTP/bbz/377342/)

Comment: Maybe I can get a better answer starting a bounty.

Comment: Not sure you are going to get a better answer - the issue is almost certainly to do with missing, broken or unapplied migrations. Also, you need to post the full stack trace - what you have posted above only shows the exception and not the stack trace.

Comment: @solarissmoke Sorry, I don't know what you mean by the stack trace.

Comment: share your admin.py where you have registered your models, also share model file as well

Comment: Try deleting and recreating the DB file and see if it helps?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Don't know what you mean by the DB file either.

Comment: Looking at the exception it seems you are using the SQLite DB and i talking the DB file that gets created when you use the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says,
the column `entry_id` in the table `learning_logs_example` does not exist.
This is not normal.
If schema migrations were created correctly and applied correctly,
then this should not happen.

Moreover, looking at this:

> ```
> (venv) C:\...\learning log>python manage.py migrate
> Operations to perform:
>   Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
> Running migrations:
>   No migrations to apply.
> ```

The `Apply all migrations` line should contain the name of your app.
The existing names are standard Django components.
The name of your app is probably `learning_log` or similar.
In short,
it seems that migrations don't exist for your app.

To debug this,
first of all check the output of `showmigrations` for your app:

```
./manage.py showmigrations learning_log
```

If you don't get an error, then please add the output to your question.

If you get an error `CommandError: No migrations present for: ...`,
then create the migrations:

```
./manage.py makemigrations learning_log
```

And then check the output of `showmigrations` again,
and please add the output to your question.

If the output looks something like this:

```
learning_log
 [X] 0001_initial
 ...
```

That means the database has some records about applied migrations,
and in fact Django thinks that the migrations are correctly applied.
(When in fact they are not, based on your main error.)

With the information I have so far,
it seems your database got out of sync with the model:
some fields have been added to the model without applying to the database,
and the migrations were not correctly saved.

One simple solution could be to manually add the missing columns.
You can find the correct schema by looking at the migration file:

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate learning_log 0001
```

From this you should be able to find how the missing `entry_id` field is declared,
and then manually add it to the table with a query `ALTER TABLE learning_logs_example ADD COLUMN entry_id ...`,
where the rest of the parameters depend on the definition of the column in the output of `sqlmigrate`.

If the problem is only one or a few missing fields,
then this workaround may be enough to have something working.
*(If not, then jump to the next section.)*
You should not stop there though,
because the model may need some indexes as well.
You could either study further output of `sqlmigrate` and recreate all other objects that depend on `learning_logs_example`,
such as indexes, triggers.
But a cleaner solution will be to recreate all the tables of the app,
following these steps:

- Dump the current data: `./manage.py dumpdata learning_log > learning_log.json`
- Drop all tables of the app
- Recreate the tables of the app: `./manage.py migrate --fake learning_log zero; ./manage.py migrate learning_log`
- Restore the data: `./manage.py loaddata learning_log`

---

If the workaround of adding columns manually doesn't work
(you stumble into more complicated problems),
then you have two choices:

- If you cannot afford to lose data, well then you will have to track down and solve every single problem manually. After that's done, you should dump and restore the tables of the app as I explained in the previous section
- If it's ok to lose data, then you can follow the procedure in the previous section, without the dumping and restoring steps. That is, drop and recreate the tables of the app

---

Finally,
to avoid further problems,
you need to make sure that all migrations are in sync with the model,
and are correctly added to version control.
A good way to test that is install the Django project in a different folder on your computer.
If that doesn't go smoothly,
then the setup is still not good.

---

Let me know if any of the above needs more clarification.

Comment: "From this you should be able to find how the missing `entry_id` field is declared, and then manually add it to the table with a query `ALTER TABLE learning_logs_example ADD COLUMN entry_id` ..., where the rest of the parameters depend on the definition of the column in the output of `sqlmigrate`.". I don't understand I'm supposed to add it because I don't know how to add it, and I still don't understand how I'm supposed to fix it that way.

Comment: Also how do I drop all tables of the app?

Comment: @BryanZeng To drop all tables of the app, connect to the database with `./manage.py dbshell`, view the list of tables with `.tables`, and for each table whose name starts with "learning_logs", run a query `drop table the_name`

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first time you are creating migrations for your application? If so, you need to specify the app name to make the migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations my-app
```

Comment: No, but I can try.

Comment: Doesn't help. Starting a bounty.

Comment: Have you added your application in `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings? If so, could you show this portion of your settings file as well as the output of `python manage.py showmigrations`?

Comment: Yes i did put it in `INSTALLED_APPS`

Answer (score 0):

If data isn't matter, you can just drop your database file from here:

> C:\Users\bryan_8nva8ki\Desktop\learning logs\db.sqlite3

(I saw that path from your logs)

Then you should make `migrate` again. Hope it will helps!

Comment: Thanks. (By the way the path supposed to be `C:\Users\bryan_8nva8ki\Desktop\learning logs\` , I just moved it for easoer access.)